# How to pass values from variable in setProperty of jmeter

Tags: testing, properties, automation, jmeter

I have a setup thread group which sets the property value and in Thread group i am using the variable in csv data set configure

[image]

[image]

it is working if i am giving values like 
${__setProperty(${name},_id.csv)} but if i take _id.csv from an array it is not reading the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts as:

1. It may resolve into something causing script compilation failure
2. It may conflict with Groovy [GString templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html)
3. It conflicts with [compilation caching](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/compile-groovyscript-at-runtime-allow-caching-of-compiled-source-to-avoid-recompilation-at-runtime-using-groovyclassloader/) feature

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, so the references will only be resolved once. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error. In order to use runtime variables, please use the appropriate props methods, e.g.
>
> ```
> props.get("START.HMS");
>
> props.put("PROP1","1234");
> ```

So you need to amend your code as follows:

```
def name = 'file'
def files = ['_id.csv']
props.put(name, files[0])
```

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.